# How to track downloads in AWStats when no file extension

Tags: joomla, awstats

I have a Joomla site, and I have a lot of downloads whose links are of the form

```
/item/download/60_7372007fc87frju9ebed04j8e65
```

AWStats is not tracking, and I suspect it is because I have to configure it to track when there is a download link of this form. Any ideas on how to get AWStats to track?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can do that in AWStats or if it can be done. But you can track that monthly by connecting to the server (in ssh), changing the /home/[your-user]/logs folder, extracting the log, and then running the following command:

```
grep "file-you-want-to-track" log-file | wc -l
```

The above should give you a count of how many have visited that download link